# Convert pandas DataFrame to list of JSON-strings

Tags: python, json, pandas, elasticsearch

I need to know how to implement `to_json_string_list()` function in that case:

```
df = pandas.read_json('[{"rec1" : "val1", "rec2" : "val4"}, {"rec1" : "val3", "rec2" : "val4"}]', orient='records')
json_strings = list()
json_strings = to_json_string_list(df)
for json_string in json_strings:
    print(json_string)
```

to get output like:

> {"rec1" : "val1", "rec2" : "val4"}
>   {"rec1" : "val3", "rec2" : "val4"}

I know that there are function `to_json(orient='records')`, but it is not that I need, because I get:

> [{"rec1" : "val1", "rec2" : "val4"},
>   {"rec1" : "val3", "rec2" : "val4"}]

Printing is not only thing I will do with this strings, so simple substitution of   `[],` is not what I need, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with parameter `lines=True`:

```
print (df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True))
{"rec1":"val1","rec2":"val4"}
{"rec1":"val3","rec2":"val4"}

df.to_json('file.json',orient='records', lines=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with this lines next thing I need is to `split()` this string by linefeed to get list?

Comment: I think yes, `a = df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)

print (a.split('\n'))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using a comprehension list:

```py
[dict(v) for _, v in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another method which gives you the reverse of pd.Daa

```
import json
json_lst = []
for i in (range(len(df)): 
    d = json.loads(df.iloc[i, :].to_json())
    json_lst.append(d)
```